# ¿como convertir el dato que almacena la key de un objeto dentro de una array de objetos a su dato requerido o original nodejs?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, json, express, backend

¿hola buenos días hoy tengo una duda hay alguna manera de tomar una array de objetos cualquiera?

que contenga datos en las keys que contienen `numero` a veces son `string` en vez de un `int` , pero como son distintos `array` porque les puedo pasar varios con distinta estructura, ***no puedo hacer una validación ya por cada archivo, ya que son distintos***, existe o hay alguna manera de validar los datos de cada `key del objeto` aquellos que sean `booleanos` o `int` sean identificados como lo que son y los convierta de `string` a sus dichos tipos de datos (recibo ideas o ayudas se los agradecería mucho)¨

ejemplo del array (son distintos los array no siempre va a ser, este puede variar mucho)

```
[

  { id_harmonized_survey: '2', iso: 'ARG' },

  { id_harmonized_survey: '3', iso: 'ARG' },

  { id_harmonized_survey: '4', iso: 'ARG' },

  { id_harmonized_survey: '5', iso: 'ARG' },

  { id_harmonized_survey: '6', iso: 'ARG' },

  { id_harmonized_survey: '7', iso: 'ARG' },

  { id_harmonized_survey: '8', iso: 'ARG' },

  { id_harmonized_survey: '9', iso: 'ARG' }

]
```

este `array` contiene 8 objetos en total cada objeto tiene dos `key` estas `key` el `ID` se muestra como un `string` cuando debería ser un `int`, pero acá viene la duda del millón como puedo convertir ese `int` en cualquier tipo de columna(`key`) del objeto sin importar,

validando si el dato solo es un `numero o bullenao` para que deje de ser un `string`

Comment: ***que contenga datos en las keys que contienen numero a veces son string en vez de un int***. Trato de entender lo que preguntas, pero es muy difícil. ¿Puedes mostrar ejemplos de cómo serían los objetos y qué es lo que pretendes? Considera crear un [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras claro ya he actualizado la información correspondiente

Comment: Teniendo un valor de cadena, ¿cómo discriminas que deba ser booleano o numérico? Del ejemplo que muestras el campo `iso` también es cadena. Tu pregunta es: ¿cómo convertir un valor de cadena en número o booleano siempre y cuando se pueda? Porque el valor del campo `iso` no se puede convertir en un número, ya que no es una cadena que represente un número, y tampoco puedo convertirlo en booleano, ya que no representa uno, a menos que aquí entren en juego los valores *truthy*, siendo una cadena vacía la única equivalente a `false`. Dada esa entrada del ejemplo, ¿cuál sería la salida esperada?

Comment: Por otro lado, ¿Qué has intentado hacer? Porque no veo en tu pregunta ningún tipo de intento por resolver el problema. Recuerda que aquí no lo haremos por ti. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras hola mauro por mi parte lo e intentado resolver pero no e llegado a punto entendible ya que muchas personas confunden el proceso ya que en verdad lo que busco como tal es que sin inportar el objeto que le pase tendran informacion ramdon la cual inpide que yo pueda hacer eso que dices porque en realidad ya lo provee a lo que me refiero es si es posible sin importar el objeto y sus key puedo cambiarlos sin necesidad de mapear o requerir el objeto manual y decirle donde cambiar los datos manualmente pero igual muchas gracias

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es que recorras cada objeto por sus claves y verifiques si el tipo de dato es de cadena y se puede convertir a número o a un valor booleano (supongo que será una cadena con "true" o "false") y hagas la conversión correspondiente.